# Autocompletion with OpenAI API or Langchain

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain, azure-openai

Assume I have some sort of text like

"This is a"

and now I want to use the OpenAI package for Python or even better Langchain to complete this statement, such that something like

"This is a question in Stackoverflow"

arises. How would I do that?

Comment: what would be the context so that it can complete your statement ?

Comment: Could be some sentences before and a non-compete sentence. Then it should write new text to possibly complete an entire paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to achieve this, I tried below code sample

```
        from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
        from langchain.prompts.chat import (
            ChatPromptTemplate,
            SystemMessagePromptTemplate,
            HumanMessagePromptTemplate,
        )
        from langchain.chains import LLMChain

        template = """You are a helpful assistant in completing following sentence based on the previous sentence. 
                        You always complete the sentence in same line
                        
                        Example : One of the top trending question on stackoverflow is "What difference between Langchain and LLAMA index ? This is a " 
                        AI : This is a ""stackoverflow question""

                        Example : What is US dollar falling ? This is a " 
                        AI : This is a ""economics question""
                        """

        system_message_prompt = SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(template)
        human_template = "{text}"
        human_message_prompt = HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(human_template)

        chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([system_message_prompt, human_message_prompt])
        chain = LLMChain(
            llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=1),
            prompt=chat_prompt,
            verbose=True
        )
        print(chain.run("War should be stopped and love should prevail. This is a "))
```

Comment: Many thanks for your input. Do we really need the Chat model and not the LLM version in Langchain?

Comment: not required this is just one way, you can use LLMs if it fits your usecase

Comment: Would there be any reason to prefer one over the other? Do you know how the LLM version would be implemented?

Comment: When you specifically need chat application you can select Chat Model, if you need general LLM applications using GPT for various tasks you can select LLM